# By using python: Is there a way to check if an Excel file in SharePoint has been edited/changed?

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

I currently have a Python program that downloads an Excel file from SharePoint everytime I run it. However I would like the Python program to check for changes to the Excel file every X amount of time and download the file automatically if it has been changed. [In the image here you can see the "Manual" action that I want to change to the "Automatic" action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBe7T.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!Please add what you researched and what you have tried so far in order to achieve your goal. You can refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines about how to ask a good question so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store hashes of files to track changes.
Suppose you have file with hash H1, if there is any small amount of change, its hash would change. You can look up SHA256 or MD5 for your purpose